# Iterating on values of a org.json.JSONObject to apply different actions to JSONObjects or JSONArrays

Tags: java, java-8, org.json

I have to do something like this:

```
JSONObject obj;
Iterator keys = obj.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()){
    String key = keys.next();
    if(obj.get(key) instanceof JSONOBject){
        //do something
    }
    else if(obj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray){
       //do something else
    } else {
      //do something even different
    }

}
```

I would like to refactor this with something nicer without instanceof and so many if else. Maybe using streams and optionals but I haven't found a good way to use them with JSONObjects yet. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `ActionMap` class that maps classes to operations you want to apply (sample code at the bottom for reference). Then you can simply populate the actions:

```
ActionMap m = new ActionMap();
m.put(JSONOBject.class, o -> System.out.println("JSONObject: " + o));
m.put(JSONArray.class, o -> System.out.println("JSONArray: " + o));
//etc.
```

and use the map in your loop:

```
while(keys.hasNext()){
  String key = keys.next();
  Object o = obj.get(key);
  if (m.containsMapping(o)) m.apply(o);
  else //deal with missing class mapping
}
```

Simplified implementation of the `ActionMap` class:

```
static class ActionMap {
  private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> actions = new HashMap<> ();

  <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    actions.put(clazz, consumer);
  }

  <T> boolean containsMapping(T obj) {
    return actions.containsKey(obj.getClass());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  <T> void apply(T obj) {
    Consumer<T> action = (Consumer<T>) actions.get(obj.getClass());
    //null check
    action.accept(obj);
  }
}
```